# Some question about NAT Penetration with UPnP

Tags: nat, upnp

I'm implementing a protection system for household network. There are several digital devices in the home, and they all have web services running on them in order that they can visit each other easily.
To visit them outside home, I need UPnP to penetrate the NAT.
My question is: Is there any authentication in the UPnP server to protect my private network, or I have to implement it for all my digital devices which have web services running on?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: no, there is not. This is a weak aspect of UPnP.